# Chai-as-promised, Promised array must be loosely-equal

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

Is there a way to assert that a promise array equals your gold standard, minus ordering?  Deep equal fails because the ordering isn't guaranteed - the array is being built asynchronously.

As far as I can tell, CaP doesn't include a ".should.eventually.include.all([])" or anything like that.  I don't think I'd be able to check every entry, because then where would the notify(done) be chained?

Answer (score 0):

The [Chai Things](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-things) plugin might help you.

You could for example do something like:

```
.should.eventually.include.something.that.equals(promiseA);
.should.eventually.include.something.that.equals(promiseB);
.should.eventually.include.something.that.equals(promiseC);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should be able to do it like this:

```
        Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(function (results) {
            //so check your results here
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                results[i].should.have....
            }

           //and the notify(done) is chained after this
        }).should.eventually.notify(done);
```

I hope that helps.